# When I open a new form program closed automatically

Tags: c#, ms-access

When I run my program, only the first form shows up, when I try to open another one, it closes and I get these 4 messages [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC2gs.png)
I have no idea what to do, does anyone know how I could fix it?

I get the errors while executing this code:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I tried to make it capital but it did not work 
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwjA8.png) after the project closed

Comment: Those are just info messages, they are not real errors. Beginning a method with a capital letter is just a practice, not a real rule that prevents your code from being correctly compiled and run. Your error must be somewhere else. You probably just have to learn proper debugging, going line by line to see what happens and how to fix the unintended behavior

Comment: They are not error message, they just are some suggestions to simplify your codes.

Comment: @DavideVitali is there is any way i can fint where is my errors cuz i didnt touch any of my codes

Comment: @Johnwiliam you’ll have to hit F5 and then F11 a bunch of times ;)

Comment: @DavideVitali a added a new pic can you look at it may be you now some thing and when i tried f11 the static void main was 0 refrence

Comment: @Johnwiliam code 0 means it has stopped with no errors. Try setting a breakpoint in your code where you try to call the second form and then hit F11 to execute every single instruction after that and try to understand what happens

Comment: Turn on [break on all Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown) and you should see if an exception is thrown.

Comment: after the debug i got this error


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point LogIn_Form C:\Users\Mhamad\Desktop\form\LogIn_Form\LogIn_Form\CSC 1 Active